# computer aided RC airplane combat

Tags: mobile-robot, sensors

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Vh_R1NlmX0 is from 2011 SWARM and shows RC aircraft or combat wings trying to hit each other in the air.

Scoring a hit is pretty rare, and I'd like to increase a pilot's chances by using a computer targeting system.  It would be an offline system that gets data from sensors on the airplane.

What sensor(s) would work for this application?

Comment: Must the sensors be passive or can they be active, e.g. can you put a radio tag on the opponents?

Comment: I'd prefer not to add anything else to the enemy airplanes.

Comment: In that case, what passive sensors can you add to your aircraft?

Comment: ultrasonic range finders.  IR LEDs and reflective IR light sensors.  A cheap camera.  Microphones (motor is probably too noisy).  A cheap laser range finder.  Something that detects the magnetic fields?

Comment: The camera seems promising. How would you use the others to increase the pilot's chances? Also, how do you plan to get the data from the aircraft to your offline system?

Comment: For getting the data off this https://store.3drobotics.com/products/3dr-radio.  With 4 ultrasonic range finders positioned in a diamond shape you can tell you are pointed at the target when all readings match, and the computer acts as a PD controller. A camera sensor is for CV, not human vision because humans are probably too slow. Optical flow is another sensor too http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_flow

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12059/discussion-between-selden-and-daemonmaker)